# Unit(s) of a gradient

Tags: units, differentiation, dimensional-analysis

Suppose I have a function $f(r, \theta) = r\sin\theta$ with $r$ being in meters and $\theta$ being in radians. The gradient of $f$ is $\nabla f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\hat{r} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \hat{\theta} = (\sin\theta) \hat{r} + (r\cos\theta)\hat{\theta}$.

Would I be correct to say that, once evaluated, the unit of the first component of $\nabla f$ is $dimensionless$ and the unit of the second component of $\nabla f$ is the $meter$?

If I am correct, the conclusion would contradict [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/172831/126986). But, if I am wrong, the conclusion would contradict $[\frac{\partial a}{\partial b}] = [\frac{a}{b}]$, taken from [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/28954/126986).

To be more succinct: What is resultant unit of the function $f$ after the del operator is applied?

Comment: Hi goo, please don't edit the answer into the question as you did. I've removed it for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think, your definition of the gradient is wrong, have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formulae). You should have some prefactors which fix the dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you're excluding the **unit** vectors from your dimensions.  Would the first component of $\nabla f$ not have units of **meters**, and the second have units of **meters $\cdot$ radians**?

Comment: Unit vectors are dimensionless.